# Why my maps cannot show on new Place Picker SDK?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I try this SDK

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.1.0'
```

This is my code

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
    Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR_API_KEY");
}
List<Place.Field> fields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME);

// Start the autocomplete intent.
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
    .build(this);
startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And this is my Log cat

```
2019-05-21 17:21:52.921 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@50aa60a[Transaction]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
2019-05-21 17:21:53.076 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@50aa60a[Transaction]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.172 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: setView = DecorView@97eb784[AutocompleteActivity] TM=true MM=false
2019-05-21 17:21:53.172 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@50aa60a[Transaction]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
2019-05-21 17:21:53.175 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom V/InputMethodManager: Not IME target window, ignoring
2019-05-21 17:21:53.177 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: dispatchAttachedToWindow
2019-05-21 17:21:53.187 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
2019-05-21 17:21:53.187 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][0,0] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x7 surface={valid=true 547448614912} changed=true
2019-05-21 17:21:53.194 13555-13602/com.pripun.ecom D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000,  [1080x1920]-format:1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.194 13555-13602/com.pripun.ecom D/OpenGLRenderer: eglCreateWindowSurface = 0x7f8a0190b0
2019-05-21 17:21:53.216 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 0) or=1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.217 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.232 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom V/InputMethodManager: Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@6a3d76 nm : com.pripun.ecom ic=com.android.internal.widget.EditableInputConnection@b3a4f77
2019-05-21 17:21:53.233 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom I/InputMethodManager: startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
2019-05-21 17:21:53.262 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 750) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 750) or=1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.263 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2019-05-21 17:21:53.264 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom I/chatty: uid=10658(u0_a658) com.pripun.ecom identical 3 lines
2019-05-21 17:21:53.264 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
2019-05-21 17:21:53.265 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2272 bytes, containing 1 windows, 10 views
2019-05-21 17:21:53.266 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom W/IInputConnectionWrapper: performPrivateCommand on inactive InputConnection
2019-05-21 17:21:53.268 13555-13565/com.pripun.ecom I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=1009KB, data=632KB
2019-05-21 17:21:53.269 13555-13565/com.pripun.ecom I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=1009KB, data=632KB
2019-05-21 17:21:53.269 13555-13565/com.pripun.ecom I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 3MB
2019-05-21 17:21:53.274 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 547448614912} changed=false
2019-05-21 17:21:53.316 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@50aa60a[Transaction]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 873) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 873) or=1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.317 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 1920) ci=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 873) vi=Rect(0, 72 - 0, 873) or=1
2019-05-21 17:21:53.338 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@50aa60a[Transaction]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 547475845120} changed=false
2019-05-21 17:21:53.352 13555-13555/com.pripun.ecom D/ViewRootImpl@4503997[AutocompleteActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x1 surface={valid=true 547448614912} changed=false
```

I try this newest code on google places, but maps not show just blank, but the autocomplete is working. [Link](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration)

Comment: Did you check your Logcat?

Comment: @Jaymin i have add my logcat on my question..

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the Place Picker has been deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. Please note that the old users that used Places SDK for iOS/Android are the only one who can still use the Place Picker during the deprecation period. The use of Places SDK for both platforms are now through enabling Places API and does not support the use of Place Picker anymore. You may see the deprecation notice in https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/placepicker.

In addition to this, Google is conducting a review on what drives the users to use the Place Picker, if you are interested, kindly add your answer in the form mentioned in this issue (Android) issuetracker.google.com/128304810, (iOS) issuetracker.google.com/128304760.